# How can we add a delay on the message which is present in azure service bus queue using java?

Tags: java, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to add a delay on the message which is present on the service bus queue using java .So that after the delay the same message can be consumed for processing by the function app.

Can anyone suggest me the sample code or links for the same ?

Comment: The message is already there in the queue. Right?

Comment: @GauravMantri  Yes the message is already there in the queue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible to add delay to a message that is already present in a Service Bus Queue.

Each Service Bus Message has a [`ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusmessage.scheduledenqueuetime?view=azure-dotnet#azure-messaging-servicebus-servicebusmessage-scheduledenqueuetime) property that can be set when a message is sent to the Queue which will ensure that the message will appear in the Queue at that time only so that it can be consumed.

However you cannot change this property for an existing message. What you can do is resubmit a message (essentially create a copy of the original message) with a desired value set for `ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc` property. Please take a look at [`public CompletableFuture scheduleMessageAsync(IMessage message, Instant scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient?view=azure-java-stable#com-microsoft-azure-servicebus-queueclient-schedulemessageasync(com-microsoft-azure-servicebus-imessage-java-time-instant)) for more details.

Comment: ok .. Thanks a lot Gaurav. This explanation has clarified lot of questions.